# Convert xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject() to Jquery Fade Effect

Tags: jquery

Some years ago I hacked away at a script I found online to change some page content using Javascript and the GetXmlHttpObject methods. All in all in works great as you can see on this page -

[Downtown Transmission Staff](http://www.downtowntransmission.com/staff.asp)

If you click on a staff member it takes you to his (her) profile with a link that reads "Next Member" in the top right.

The code for this is as follows:

```
<span id='next_staff'  onClick="change(8,'staff',1)"  >Next Team Member</span>
```

So I am passing three parameters, one is the id of the staff member, the word staff is for a switch statement, and the number 1 is to tell the script the shop the staff member belongs to (some clients have multiple shops).

My goal is to keep the same url structure for each staff, such as "?member=5&shop=1" in the url but convert the javascript I am using to give me a nice jquery effect such as a fade or slide on the conntent.

I would assume that since I am already fetching the content and it is working I should be able to modify the javascript for jquery - no?

I tried but could not insert my code, but you can see it at [Javascript Code](http://www.downtowntransmission.com/next.js)

I really would appreciate any help, I've been using another source online for years but this website keeps coming up as I search for help. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose not the best solution, but with minimal changes:

```
function stateChanged(){ 
   if (xmlHttp.readyState==4){ 
        var xmlDoc=xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement;
        $("#staff_profile").fadeOut(100, function() {
            switch(typex){
                case 'service':
                //...
                break;   
            case 'staff':
                 document.getElementById("staffnameheader").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("stafftitle")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                 document.getElementById("staffdesc").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("staffdescription")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                 document.getElementById("staffimg").src = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("staffimage")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                 document.getElementById("navbutton").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("nextstaff")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;  
            break;
            case 'affiliate':
               //...
            break;
            }
            $("#staff_profile").fadeIn(100);
      });
   }
}
```